# How to filter a flattened LINQ result in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, flatten

I have a JSON response containing a list of several Jobs, each of which can have Tags, and the Tags consist of key/value pairs, where the Value is a list of values. I'm trying to form a LINQ query in C# that returns a list of Job IDs where each Job has a Tag with Key="Area" and Value contains "Test".

I've successfully managed to deserialize the JSON into classes, but I'm new to LINQ and have consumed a ton of hours experimenting and Googling possible solutions to this, to no avail.

Sample data:

```cs
    {
    jobs: [
        {
            id: 1
            tags: [
                {
                    key: "Area"
                    values: [ "TEST", "SHIP" ]
                }
        }
        {
            id: 2
            tags: [
                {
                    key: "Area"
                    values: [ "BUILD" ]
                }
        }
        {
            id: 3
            tags: [
                {
                    key: "Area"
                    values: [ "INSPECT", "TEST", "SHIP" ]
                }
                {
                    key: "Status"
                    values: [ "HOLD", "SPECIAL" ]
                }
        }
        {
            id: 4
            tags: [
                {
                    key: "Area"
                    values: [ "BUILD", "TEST" ]
                }
        }]
    }
```

Class structure:

```cs
    public class Tag
        {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public List<string> values { get; set; }
        }

    public class Job
        {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
        }
```

So what I want is a list of **Job.id** where **job.tags** contains a **Tag** where **Tag.values** contains "TEST". In this sample,

```
1
3
4
```

Any LINQ experts have an idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var result = jobs.Where(j =>    j.tags != null 
                             && j.tags.Any(t =>   t.key.Equals("Area") 
                                               && t.values.Contains("TEST")))
                 .Select( x => x.id)
                 .ToList();
```

`result` would be `List` of `int` containing 1,3,4

Comment: [MacKey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284346/mackey) pointed out that `t.values.Contain(` should be `t.values.Contains(`, but didn't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: @seanskelly & mackey  yes you are correct. Edited. Thank you

Comment: This seems to work in a sandbox, but I'm encountering an exception when I run across jobs with no tasks. Based on the call stack, it looks like the Any method can't take a null value.

Comment: @DaveNicks Yes, if `j.tags` is null then `Any()` will throw exception. But adding a null check will fix it. Look at edited answer. You might have to add similar null checks for `t.key` and `t.values`